# Unix awk how to pass variable to the print statement

Tags: variables, unix, awk

I am trying to print the filename with the output of the command below

```
less $file|awk -F' ' '{print '$file' $2,$3,$5}
```

it prints without the variable value

```
x y z
a b c
```

I want to print

```
file1 x y z
file1 a b c
```

Comment: `less file | awk` makes no sense. Use `awk '{print ...}' file | less`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
`awk -F' ' '{print FILENAME " " $2 " " $3 " " $5}' $file`

FILENAME is a built-in variable of awk, representing the input filename.